# Java - Simple exception handling query

Tags: java, exception, throw

Just a quick question that I can't seem to find a proper answer to online.

When I have a try/catch block, and I want to catch an error, should I use `System.err.println(...)` or should I use `throw new Exception(...)`.

For example:

```
if (null==userList || null==credentials)
    System.err.println("Did you call login() first?");
else
{
    try
    {
        currentUser=(String) userList.nextElement();
        currentPass=(String) credentials.get(currentUser);          
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException nsee)
    {
        System.err.println("Is properties file blank?");
        //Or should this be
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Is properties file blank?");
        nsee.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

EDIT: So is `throw` not meant to go inside the `catch`? Can I use `throw` instead of `catch` or is it just for method signatures?? 
What is the correct method of catching an error in this case, where I'll be trying to ensure the properties file is not blank and contains values?
Also, for clarity, my goal is to make it as clear as possible to the user what the error is, so they know straight away that they need to fix their properties file.

Comment: I think they're distinct issues - System.err is mainly for debugging

Comment: An odd question. The decision to re-throw seems unrelated to whether or where you want to log it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do.

If the contract of your method **can't be fulfilled** in case of an exception (i.e. you can't return the value you intended to for instance) throw a new exception. (Note however that just rethrowing a new exception doesn't make much sense. Just declare the method as `throws NoSuchELementException` and let the exception propagate.)

If your contract **can be fulfilled** in case of an exception (i.e. you could return `null` if no element is found) then you should catch the exception (log it using `System.err.println` if you like) and then continue execution.

---

A side-note on the first option of throwing a new exception:

You should always throw an exception which is **appropriate for the current level of abstraction**. If for instance the method is called `getUserFromList(...)` and you encounter a `NoSuchElementException` due to some collection-related problem, you should catch the exception and throw a `NoSuchUserException`.

To highlight the difference:

```
try {
    currentUser=(String) userList.nextElement();
    currentPass=(String) credentials.get(currentUser);          

} catch(NoSuchElementException nsee) {
              ^^^^^^^

    System.err.println("Is properties file blank?");
    throw new NoSuchUserException("Is properties file blank?");
                    ^^^^
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That would depend on what your goal is.  If your goal is to provide more context to whoever is interpreting the logs, then you could chain the exception, wrapping it in a more domain-specific one.

For example, you could create a runtime exception called `ConfigurationException` and rethrow it like this:

```
} catch(NoSuchElementException nsee) {
   throw new ConfigurationException("Expected non-blank properties file", nsee);
}
```

Typically, it is best not to log directly to `System.err` (since your users probably won't be looking at it) but rather to configure a logging framework (log4j, slf4j, Java Logging API, etc).  Then you can configure the logger to append to the error stream if you want.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do.

If you rethrow the exception, the function will exit and the exception will be re-caught further up the call stack.

If you only print the stack trace, control is returned to the function, and you can continue execution.

The following though doesn't make sense:

```
try
{
    currentUser=(String) userList.nextElement();
    currentPass=(String) credentials.get(currentUser);          
}
catch(NoSuchElementException nsee)
{
    throw new NoSuchElementException("Is properties file blank?");
}
```

If you don't catch the exception, the calling context is responsible for it anyway. Unless you explicitly want to change the string, there's no point in doing it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do.
If you need only information about that the exception is caught [ex.: for logging then syserr is enough for you.
But if you wanna handle this exception you should throw it to the upper level and handle it there or handle it inside the catch block.
In your case you should handle it by sending back some information about the failure of getting the username/password.